# Custom CSS / meta tag for iPad/iPhone

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, extjs

I am working on a web app that uses Extjs components, PHP, and MySQL. 
I want to correctly display my apps on iPad.  Are there special CSS rules or meta tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is fairly vague. Here are some tips for developing a web application on iOS:

- For fixed width sites, use a `<meta>` tag to tell mobile Safari what the width of your site should be, similar to:
  `<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = 320, initial-scale = 2.3, user-scalable = no">`
- You can get a list of other `<meta>` tags supported by mobile Safari [here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html)
- Mobile Safari adds new events to the JavaScript DOM in order to support touch and orientation change. [Here is the Apple reference to them.](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariJSRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001482)
- Here's a [useful overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#technotes/tn2010/tn2262/) of how to make a web app suitable for use on iPad.
- Finally, try a [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=mobile+safari+touch+events).

Comment: With all that said (perfectly valid) if you aren't using a library to abstract most of this for you then you're probably doing it wrong.  There are several good alternatives (including Sencha Touch by the same folks who make Ext JS).

Comment: The problem is Ext JS is needed for fancy desktop applications, whereas Sencha Touch is most suitable for applications dedicated for mobile devices. What's needed is a framework that works well on desktop & tablet, including special adapters like my code below to bridge small differences in the two platforms' capabilities. Maybe Ext JS 4 will be that framework, but until then I, and others like the OP, will have to rely on hacking Ext JS 3.3 to suit our needs.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't gotten a chance to test it yet, but I wrote this script to fire the contextmenu event on an element after a long press of 1.5 seconds or more. Try it out.

UPDATE: finally got a chance to test it, it works as intended. I lowered the delay from 1500 ms to 1200 ms since the delay seemed too long for my taste.

```
(function() {
var EM = Ext.EventManager,
    body = document.body,
    activeTouches = {},
    onTouchStart = function(e, t) {
    var be = e.browserEvent;
    Ext.id(t);
    if(be.touches.length === 1) {
        activeTouches[t.id] = fireContextMenu.defer(1200, null, [e, t]);
    } else {
        cancelContextMenu(e, t);
    }
    },
    fireContextMenu = function(e, t) {
    var touch = e.browserEvent.touches[0];
    var me = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    me.initMouseEvent("contextmenu", true, true, window,
        1, // detail
        touch.screenX,
        touch.screenY,
        touch.clientX,
        touch.clientY,
        false, false, false, false, // key modifiers
        2, // button
        null // relatedTarget
    );
    t.dispatchEvent(me);
    },
    cancelContextMenu = function(e, t) {
    clearTimeout(activeTouches[t.id]);
    };
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null) {
    Ext.onReady(function() {
        EM.on(body, "touchstart", onTouchStart);
        EM.on(body, "touchmove", cancelContextMenu);
        EM.on(body, "touchend", cancelContextMenu);
    });
}
})();
```

Comment: thank you for the code , i use grid cellcontextmenu event , how can i do it with your function ? plz help

Comment: From looking through the Ext JS source code, it looks like the rowcontextmenu and cellcontextmenu are events that fire as a result of the element's contextmenu event. So it should just work.